# How can I make my output to be added to an existing list?

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}

For[i = 1, i < 6, i++, 
  For[e = 1, e < 6, e++ 1, 
    Print[Mod[v[[i]] + v[[e]], 2]]
]]
```

I have been trying to make all the output  from the loop  to be added to another list using `AppendTo`, but it doesn't work.

How can I do this task?

Comment: Look up `Append`

Comment: Your first problem is that your nested For-loops make no output, so there is nothing to append to any external list.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the reason for your problem because you did not show the code you attempted to use.  I shall guess that you tried to use both `Print` and `AppendTo`; that won't work because the output of `Print` is `Null`.  Also, instead of using `AppendTo` which will be very slow on long lists (because the array must be reallocated for each operation), I recommend using `Sow` and `Reap`, or even better replacing the loops entirely with `Table`, then merging the results with `v = Join[v, result]`.

`Sow` and `Reap`:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

result =
 Reap[
    For[i = 1, i < 6, i++, For[e = 1, e < 6, e++ 1, Sow[Mod[v[[i]] + v[[e]], 2]]]]
 ][[2, 1]];

v = Join[v, result];

v
```

`Table`:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

v = Join[v, Table[Mod[v[[i]] + v[[e]], 2], {i, 5}, {e, 5}] ~Flatten~ 1]
```

Even better is to use vectorized functions.  For example create your combinations using `Tuples` and apply `Mod` to all vectors at once:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

v = v ~Join~ Mod[Plus @@@ Tuples[v, 2], 2]
```

Equivalently, using `Total` instead of `Plus` and `Apply` at level one (short form `@@@`):

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}};

v = Join[v, v ~Tuples~ 2 ~Total~ {2} ~Mod~ 2]
```

In case you are wondering, `a ~f1~ b ~f2~ c` is another way to write `f2[f1[a, b], c]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice place to consider using `Outer` which calculates the outer product of a vector. Replacing the "product" with sum (`Plus`) gives the sum of all the terms. The `Mod` function can then be mapped to all the elements of the sum:

```
v = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}; 
Mod[#, 2] & /@ Flatten[Outer[Plus, v, v, 1], 1]
```

which gives the desired output

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, 
 {0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, 
 {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, 
 {0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

As Simon suggests, the somewhat simpler form:

```
Mod[Flatten[Outer[Plus, v, v, 1], 1], 2]
```

also does the job.

Comment: +1 but note that `Mod` is `Listable` so there's no need to map it: `Outer[Plus, v, v, 1] ~Flatten~ 1 ~Mod~ 2`