# Using Table[ ] vs using Do[Append [ ] ]

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, syntax

Is it generally better/faster to use the `Table` function over using `Do[Append []]`?

For example, I have this piece of code:

```
inttstar[1] = (tstar[2] - tstar[0])/8; 
inttstar[j_] := 
 inttstar[j] = (1/4)*(tstar[j + 1]/(j + 1) - 
      tstar[Abs[j - 1]]/(j - 1)) - 
        ((-1)^j*tstar[0])/(2*(j^2 - 1))
G = Table[
   Coefficient[inttstar[i], tstar[j], 1], {i, 0, m - 1}, {j, 0, 
    m - 1}];

Gt=Transpose[G];
cmat = T {{0, 1}, {-a, -d}};
cmatk = Outer[Times, cmat, Gt];

aI = {};
Do[
 Do[
  Do[aI = Append[aI, cmatk[[i, k, j]]], {k, 1, 2 n}], {j, 1, 
       m}], {i, 1, 2 n}]
```

As is, it runs correctly. But, can I improve performance by replacing the `Do[Do[Do[....]]]` section with a `Table` function? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Yes, it's recommended because the code looks better if nothing else. You simply write `Table[expression,{i,...},{j,...},{k,...}]`.

Comment: Related: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121); also see [(13100)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13100/alternatives-to-while-loops/13126#13126), [(16825)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/how-can-i-improve-my-code-for-drawing-a-tree/16850#16850), [(29349)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29349/121), [(39777)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/39777/121)

Comment: @MrW I just wrote a lengthy beginner friendly explanation of *why* AppendTo is going to be slow ... the question got closed a few seconds before I could hit the post button :-(

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you have a copy of it? :-O

Comment: Anyway, I agree that it's a duplicate, @gKirkland here's the text of what I wrote: http://pastebin.com/VRbem8Uy

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm glad you have a copy of it.  I need to leave but later I'll try to find the best place for it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Using 'Table' I was able to eliminate about a dozen lines of code. I'll look into the links provided to avoid future duplicate posts.

Comment: @Szabolcs - maybe add this as a (partial) answer in the original question that this is a dupe of?